# Centered and evenly spaced Navbar bar links w Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am in the process of transition from Bootstrap 3.3 to 4.1 and I think I am down to my final two complications. In bootstrap 3.3 I had a responsive navbar, with no branding, where the links were evenly spaced. Currently I have gotten my links to look the way I want them to but they are crowded in two rows on the far left. In delving through the past of these questions, and I know there are a lot, I have attempted to add in most of the answers that have been given. I have tried to add floats, display in-line, and others, but nothing seems to shift my links back to the left. That being said, the original css setup was done by someone other than myself as my CSS skills are minimal.

html/rails

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to 'Link 1', '#', class: "nav-link" %></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to 'Link 2', '#', class: "nav-link" %></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to 'Link 3', '#', class: "nav-link" %></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
```

CSS

```
      #main-menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border: medium none;
  }

  #main-menu ul {

  }

  #main-menu ul li {

  }

  #main-menu ul li a {
    padding: 5px 30px;
  }

  .navbar.navbar-light {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%
  }

  #main-menu .nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    @include size(md) {
      width: 795px;
    }
  }
```

[image: Debugger1]

Answer (score 0):

You can add following class to your navbar as below:
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-start" id=“main-menu”>...</div>`

The d-flex class will add Flexbox properties and justify-content-start will move links to the left. 
I hope this helps.

Comment: EDIT: Ok, they did move, but now they are completely centered and stacked instead of side by side.

Comment: Ok, they are back in the right side. I was experimenting with removing different tage. When I remove the `navbar-expand-lg(sm)`, the links all move to the center and are stacked. When I replace it, they move back to the right side.

Comment: I will need to see entire code to make suitable changes. Remove min-height:0 from navbar selector and add width:100%;  also change float from none to float:left in #main-menu to see if this changes anything.

Comment: Those changes did not shift anything. I am happy provide you with whatever code you would need. What would you like me to expand on? I am running Rails 6, Bootstrap 4.1.3, I can expand on the css file. Anything else you can think of?

Comment: Remove align-items:center from .navbar-collapse. Change flex:wrap to nowrap in .nav selector.

Comment: We have movement! All links are on one line, but still jammed to the far right. And the links with two words are now wrapped to the next line down.

Comment: I added `white-space: nowrap;` to the nav-items and that stopped that line break. Now just to get them center jusitfied on the page.

Comment: Inspect nav-item class and share it’s screenshot

Comment: I have also noticed this error message at the bottom: `Source map error: Error: Section offsets must be ordered and non-overlapping.
Resource URL: http://localhost:3001/assets/application.debug-05d395b2ba13389806a15db6aaed1d3eeb69fee9a15dcca52b0ceb64842f4ea0.css
Source Map URL: application.css-983c5bb873548913ec1409d15a57ea08e13f340026db62945a1802cf55e76541.map`

Comment: You may have given up on me, but in case you have not, I was playing with the inspector and by deleting the row 2-8 of the HTML, the text centered. I was under the impression that that was my hamburger code for small views, is that done another way now?